# How to count to the number of users who disable ads

Tags: java, android, firebase

I'm not sure how to explain it so I will give the context of what I want.

I published android app and I put advertisement in it, but the advertisement is optional, I would like to keeping track of how many people enabled it and how many people disabled it.

I believe I can use firebase events to count each time that users have disabled or enabled ads, but the problem is if people spam enable and disable ads, it will count it multiple times. A fix for it would be to subtract the number of times users disable ads from number of times users enable ads to get the number of users that enable ads.

Are there any better approach to this?

Answer (score 1):

This really depends on your tools.

At a rate of once per day(or more often) use Google Analytics to send data to you. Simple true/false will suffice. Then, do this math:

```
(total / check times) - (disabled / check times)
```

and you have the amount of users that day who has ads vs total amount. Remember, if you check more than once per day you have to divide by the amount of scans per day. Check times is not needed if you only check once per day.

What is great about this method is that you check the day after to see how many it was that day. And there is no need to check in the background, just when the user opens the app.

Using v4:

```
Tracker t = ((AnalyticsSampleApp) getActivity().getApplication()).getTracker(
TrackerName.APP_TRACKER);
// Build and send an Event.
t.send(new HitBuilders.EventBuilder()
    .setCategory("Ads")
    .setAction(Boolean.toString(isAdsActive))
    .setNonInteraction(true)
    .build());
```

As you can filter events by day you can filter to see the events that was recorded yesterday, two days ago, three days ago, today(not accurate as not all are recorded yet). You can even create java code in Eclipse to keep track of the calculations if you feel like it.

For more details on sending events, [see this](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/events)